# Select current element from getElementsbyClassName

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyclassname

This code will hide the first div, even if it were activated from the second button. What keyword should I use to get it to hide the parent div (first button hides the first div, second button hides the second div)?

```js
var x = document.getElementsbyClassName(myClass);

function myFunction() {
  x[0].display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass">
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
</div>
<div class="myClass">
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. Please update the snippet I made for you tor work. You need to quote ("myClass") and use style.display 2. I would use document.querySelector(".myClass") instead. Also pass `this` to the function and use parentElement: `onclick="myFunction(this)"` and `function myFunction(but) { but.parentElement.style.display = "none"; }`

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to anticipate which element will be clicked by the user, simply use an event-listener which can take the element that has been interacted with and respond appropriately:

```js
function hide() {

  // EventTarget.addEventListener() passes the 'this'
  // Node to the function; here 'this' is whichever
  // element was clicked:
  let target = this;

  // here we set the display of the clicked element's
  // parentNode to 'none':
  target.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
}

// here we use document.querySelectorAll(), which takes
// a CSS selector as an argument and returns an Array-Like
// nodeList of the found elements, which is passed to
// nodeList.forEach():
document.querySelectorAll('.myClass > button').forEach(

  // nodeList.forEach() iterates over the supplied nodeList,
  // to perform the supplied actions. Here we use an Arrow
  // function to perform the required action;
  // myClassElement is the current Element of the nodeList over
  // which we're iterating.
  // In the Arrow function we bind an event-listener to listen
  // for a 'click' event, which executes the supplied function
  // in response (note the deliberate omission of the parentheses;
  // we don't pass 'hide()' (unless you want to bind the result of
  // a supplied function):
  myClassElement => myClassElement.addEventListener('click', hide)
);
```

```html
<div class="myClass">
  <button>Click</button>
</div>
<div class="myClass">
  <button>Click</button>
</div>
```

In the above approach I've used an unobtrusive JavaScript approach, moving the event-handlers out of the HTML and into the JavaScript, this is better for 'pretty' HTML, but it's also better from a code-maintenance standpoint: it prevents you having to find all mentions of a function in the HTML to either remove the event-listener, or update them to a new function.

Incidentally, though, the above code should either be in a `<script>` tag at the end of the document, before the closing `</body>` tag, or in an on-ready event-handler in the `<head>` of the document; otherwise – as JavaScript runs as it's encountered – the elements you wish to bind events to won't yet be present in the DOM when the event-listeners are bound.

Comment: Make sure OP wraps that in an onload or places it after the divs

Comment: Yeah, I compose answers in stages; first the code, then code-explanations, then any relevant advice/stipulations. But genuinely: thank you for the reminder! :)

Comment: True enough, but I - for better or worse - truly dislike the use `on<eventName>`. This is why I'm a hobbyist, not a pro I suspect; I get to indulge my unrealistic expectations and preferences this way.

Comment: I used it a lot when there was a difference in event adding between IE and the rest

Answer (score 2):

If you pass on the event to the click handler, you can access the parent element through `event.target.parentElement`:

```js
function myFunction(event) {
    event.target.parentElement.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass">
    <button onclick="myFunction(event)">Click</button>
</div>
<div class="myClass">
    <button onclick="myFunction(event)">Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why pass `event` instead of `this`? Then you have `function myFunction(but) {
    but.parentElement.style.display = "none";
}`

Comment: @mplungjan I prefer that primarily to avoid me or someone else from making some closure related mistake in future.

Comment: Hmm, I would say it is pretty impossible to make closure errors when passing this to a function

Comment: @mplungjan Oh yes, I just realized what you are referring to. I still do not see any obvious benefits of one method over another. Do you know any?

Comment: The verbosity of event.target which is not actually supported by all older browsers

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you can simply do it using `this` and `parentElement`. Just pass the reference in button click and then use `parentElement` to hide it like this

```js
function myFunction(obj) {
    obj.parentElement.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass">
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)">Click</button>
</div>
<div class="myClass">
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)">Click</button>
</div>
```

**P.S** You have to use `style` before using `display` for any element

Answer (score 1):

Similar to David Thomas' answer, but mine checks if the button itself was clicked, rather than the `div`:

HTML

```
<div class="myClass">
  <button>Click</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.myClass button');

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
});

function myFunction() {
  this.parentNode.style.display = "none";
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wv4nomLb/6/)**

Comment: Why not make a snippet here instead of (or in addition to) JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="myClass">
  <button>Click</button>
</div>
<div class="myClass">
  <button>Click</button>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var btns = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].onclick = function() {
    this.parentElement.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```